# PHP Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php

A year ago, I tried this code and it worked perfectly. Now does not work, I wish someone would explain it and to learn. Thank you

**Live PHP Code:** http://codepad.viper-7.com/Qibwoz

The error appears in the apache log:

...many undefined variables...

Example:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: f in /var/www/html/eliminar2.php on line 233

-END-

---

```
    <?php
    // Get Icecat data in array by EAN number
    $data = array(
        'ean'       => '4026203907966',
        'language'  => 'ES',
        'username'  => 'user',
        'password'  => 'randompassword'
    );
    $data = icecat_to_array($data);
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($data,TRUE).'</pre>';
    ?>
    <h2>Product Specifications</h2>
    <table>
    <? foreach($spec as $id=>$s): ?>
        <tr>
            <th title="Icecat specification category ID: <?=$id;?>"><?=$s['name'];?></th>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <? foreach($s['features'] as $id=>$f): ?>
            <tr>
                <td title="Icecat specification feature ID: <?=$id;?>"><?=$f['name'];?></td>
                <td><?=$f['pres_value'];?></td>
            </tr>
        <? endforeach; ?>
    <? endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Have any `include()` files been deleted since then? Are you showing us line 233 in the above code segment? For example, we have no way of knowing if you defined `$spec` anywhere...

Comment: Another possibility is making sure short tags are set. If not, change all `<?` to `<?php` and `<?=` to `<?php echo` or set them ON.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_NONE); ini_set('display_errors',0); ` at the top of the script. Not recommended but it will make them go away.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It does not work. The html output is the same. `Product Specifications

$s): ?> $f): ?>
`

Comment: You mean to say that the actual output is `Product Specifications $s): ?> $f): ?>`?

Comment: Yes! @Fred-ii- That is the output.

Comment: That tells me that it's suddenly outside of PHP.

Comment: @Fred-ii- http://codepad.viper-7.com/Qibwoz

Comment: So you did change `<? foreach($spec as $id=>$s): ?>` to `<?php foreach($spec as $id=>$s): ?>` and `<?=$id;?>"><?=$s['name'];?>` to `<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $s['name'];?>` etc. etc. etc.? That's the only thing I can see that would make it go haywire like that.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you haven't initialized your variable. Just do

$f=0;

And the notice will disappear

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean